# Exposing COM events to VBScript (ATL)

Tags: c++, events, com, vbscript, atl

I have built a COM server DLL in C++ with ATL by using the "ATL simple object" wizard. I followed Microsoft's [ATLDLLCOMServer](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/ATLDllCOMServer-09df00e4) example. Everything works well except for one thing: **I do not receive COM events in VBScript**. I do receive the events in C#. I had events working in VBScript in an earlier MFC-based implementation as ActiveX control.

My control is defined like this:

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CSetACLCOMServer :
    public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,
    public CComCoClass<CSetACLCOMServer, &CLSID_SetACLCOMServer>,
    public IConnectionPointContainerImpl<CSetACLCOMServer>,
    public CProxy_ISetACLCOMServerEvents<CSetACLCOMServer>,
    public IDispatchImpl<ISetACLCOMServer, &IID_ISetACLCOMServer, &LIBID_SetACLCOMLibrary, /*wMajor =*/ 1, /*wMinor =*/ 0>,
    public IProvideClassInfo2Impl<&CLSID_SetACLCOMServer, &DIID__ISetACLCOMServerEvents, &LIBID_SetACLCOMLibrary>   /* Required for event support in VBS */
{
public:

BEGIN_COM_MAP(CSetACLCOMServer)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(ISetACLCOMServer)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IDispatch)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IConnectionPointContainer)
   COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IProvideClassInfo)
   COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IProvideClassInfo2)
END_COM_MAP()

BEGIN_CONNECTION_POINT_MAP(CSetACLCOMServer)
    CONNECTION_POINT_ENTRY(__uuidof(_ISetACLCOMServerEvents))
END_CONNECTION_POINT_MAP()

[...]
```

In VBScript I use the COM object like this:

```
set objSetACL = WScript.CreateObject("SetACL.SetACL", "SetACL_")

' Catch and print messages from the SetACL COM server which are passed (fired) as events.
' The name postfix of this function (MessageEvent) must be identical to the event name 
' as defined by SetACL.
' The prefix (SetACL_) can be set freely in the call to WScript.CreateObject
sub SetACL_MessageEvent (Message)
    WScript.Echo Message
end sub
```

The relevant parts of the IDL look like this:

```
[
    object,
    uuid(E1B57CA5-FD7F-4304-BC0A-8BEBDE231D53),
    dual,
    nonextensible,
    pointer_default(unique),
   helpstring("SetACL COM Interface")
]
interface ISetACLCOMServer : IDispatch
{
};

[
    uuid(00D4DCD3-02B9-4A71-AB61-2283504620C8),
    version(1.0),
   helpstring ("SetACL Type Library")
]
library SetACLCOMLibrary
{
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");

   [
        uuid(35F76182-7F52-4D6A-BD6E-1317345F98FB),
      helpstring ("SetACL Event Interface")
    ]
    dispinterface _ISetACLCOMServerEvents
    {
        properties:
        methods:
         [id(1), helpstring("Receives string messages that would appear on the screen in the command line version")]
         void MessageEvent([in] BSTR message);
   };

   [
        uuid(13379563-8F21-4579-8AC7-CBCD488735DB),
      helpstring ("SetACL COM Server"),
    ]
    coclass SetACLCOMServer
    {
        [default] interface ISetACLCOMServer;
        [default, source] dispinterface _ISetACLCOMServerEvents;
    };
};
```

The **problem**: SetACL_MessageEvent never gets called.

What I have tried:

- After reading [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;200839) I added the implementation of IProvideClassInfo2, but that did not help.
- This [FAQ](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/166480) mentions that outgoing interface should not defined as a dual interfaces. I removed the "dual" from my interface definition, but that did not help.
- I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170054/atl-com-events-for-javascript) that seems to describe a similar problem. An answer was never given, only a workaround.

**UPDATE 1:**

I know now where it is failing, but not why: in the fire event method in _ISetACLCOMServerEvents_CP.h the call to Invoke fails with E_UNEXPECTED. This is the line:

```
hr = pConnection->Invoke(1, IID_NULL, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_METHOD, &params, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

**Solution:**

The problem was that I called the event firing function from a background thread in the COM object, in other words from the wrong apartment.

Comment: Don't you have to use `WithEvents` in vbscript/vba to be able to respond to COM events ?

Comment: No, according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974564.aspx you do not.

Comment: I think you lost 2nd parameter in `IProvideClassInfo2Impl`. I should have been the events interface `IID`.

Comment: Thank you, @RomanR., I added the IID (and updated the question), but the problem persists.

Comment: You added the wrong one. You need `DIID__ISetACLCOMServerEvents` there.

Comment: Thanks @RomanR, I tried DIID__ISetACLCOMServerEvents (and updated the question accordingly) but it still does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implementation of `IProvideClassInfo2` should be sufficient (though I was under impression that it should work even without it). I created a minimalistic ATL project from template as a sample. This is ATL DLL + COM Class + a method and an event + `IProvideClassInfo2`:

Source code [[SVN](http://www.alax.info/svn/public/trunk/Utilities/VbsEvents/), [Browser Friendly](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/VbsEvents)] + [Win32 Binary](http://www.alax.info/svn/public/trunk/Utilities/VbsEvents/Release/).

Test `.vbs` is the following:

```
Function Test_Event(Text)
  WScript.Echo "Event: " + Text
End Function

Dim Test
Set Test = WScript.CreateObject("AlaxInfo.VbsEvents.Foo", "Test_")
Test.Method("Event Fun")
```

And the method itself is:

```
// IFoo
    STDMETHOD(Method)(BSTR sText) throw()
    {
        ATLTRACE(atlTraceCOM, 4, _T("sText \"%s\"\n"), CString(sText));
        ATLVERIFY(SUCCEEDED(Fire_Event(sText)));
        return S_OK;
    }
```

And having executed this, the output is:

[image]

I thought you might be having issues with events in your sample project if you are firing them from a background thread. You can also step your project with debugger and check if you have any errors in the `Fire_` call.

Comment: Thanks, your project builds and works fine. I compared every file to mine, but could not spot any meaningful difference. As I found out, in my project the call to the fire method's invoke fails - I have updated the question.

Comment: Would you show your project? I would check your proxy class. Maybe after certain modifications it is no longer in match with IDL.

Comment: I deleted and regenerated the connection point proxy class - no change. I have uploaded the project - if you'd like to take a look: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B_otVBEVufIiazV1MzBmb2Y2Y28 (download with File->Download)

Comment: Your IDL and proxy class - they are good. I can think of your firing the event off wrong thread, or another COM related issue.

Comment: You did not follow up, but I came across this Q once again. I think you should try putting event firing call right into the COM method, similarly to what I have [in my code](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/VbsEvents/Foo.h#L59). You should have this working, and when you move the code into a different place it stops working, which makes me think it is fired off wrong thread. But it is you to confirm this because you have the buildable code. You could just check the threading, and with COM you are not allowed to call from wrong apartment...

Comment: Thank you! Somehow I did not think properly about the threading issue you mentioned. As it is, I am firing the event from a background thread. A quick test from the COM class's thread worked immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn your VBScript function into `IDispatch*` pointers. For example the `onreadystatechange` handler in the `Microsoft.XMLHTTP` object.

```
Option Explicit
Dim xmlhttp
Function OnReadyStateChange
  WScript.Echo "ReadyState: " & xmlhttp.readyState
End Function
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = GetRef("OnReadyStateChange")
xmlhttp.open "GET", "http://stackoverflow.com", True
xmlhttp.send
WScript.Echo "Waiting for 20 seconds to allow OnReadyStateChange events to finish."
WScript.Sleep 20000
WScript.Echo "Done!"
```

Outputs:

```
ReadyState: 1
Waiting for 20 seconds to allow OnReadyStateChange events to finish.
ReadyState: 2
ReadyState: 3
ReadyState: 4
Done!
```

Extracting the IDL for `C:\Windows\System32\msxml3.dll` shows we're setting an `IDispatch*` property:

```
[
  odl,
  uuid(ED8C108D-4349-11D2-91A4-00C04F7969E8),
  helpstring("IXMLHTTPRequest Interface"),
  dual,
  oleautomation
]
interface IXMLHTTPRequest : IDispatch {
    // ...
    [id(0x0000000e), propput, helpstring("Register a complete event handler")]
    HRESULT onreadystatechange([in] IDispatch* rhs);
};
```

When adapting this approach to your C++ application, your calling code will need to use `IDispatch::Invoke` with a DISPID of `DISPID_VALUE`, for example:

```
// IDispatch* pOnReadyStateChange <-- set from VBScript.
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
CComVariant vResult;
EXCEPINFO ei = { };
DISPPARAMS dispParams = { NULL, 0, 0, 0 };
hr = pOnReadyStateChange->Invoke(
    DISPID_VALUE,
    IID_NULL,
    0,
    DISPATCH_METHOD,
    &dispParams,
    &vResult,
    &ei,
    NULL);
```