# What is the purpose of using a prefix with WScript.CreateObject?

Tags: c++, vbscript, com, createobject

Does anyone know the actual purpose of using a prefix when using `WScript.CreateObject`?

I have a C++ COM project example and it has a VB Script file that calls a method of COM object that's in the C++ dll project.

```
Function Testing_Event(Text)
  WScript.Echo CStr(Text)
End Function

Dim Test
Set Test = WScript.CreateObject("Hello.World", "Testing_")
Test.Method("Hello World!")
```

I also found an another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713418/exposing-com-events-to-vbscript-atl/11725613#11725613) that have the same calling behavior with a prefix.

Above works fine with VB Script, but if I remove the prefix, wscript runs but outputs nothing like before.

Please can anyone explain me what is the usage of `Testing_` prefix here? Is it possible to stop using that prefix and call this method normally like `Hello.World`? Do I need to make any changes to example's source files to call this method without this prefix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Testing_` is an event prefix, so in your example when `Test` raises an event called `Event` then *prefix+event_name* maps to `Testing_Event` and that local procedure is called.

If you omit the prefix then no events will be sunk, so if you need events you need the prefix.

The rationale for doing it this way is that it it allows multiple instances of the same class to raise their own independent events by specifying different prefixes.

Comment: Thanks much! I understood a lot, but what about echoed message `Text` variable? Is this variable gets assigned by this `Test.Method`?

Comment: `Test.Method("Hello World!")` calls the `Method()` method in the COM server, if that method raises an event called `Event` (passing back the same string as an argument) then  `Testing_Event` is called and does the echo.

Comment: Okay, if I want to do this anyway (just to understand) without this prefix, what should I need to do before removing it from `CreateObject`? Can it be done from some source editing? I will expect to use this source until I understand how this works.

Comment: You cannot catch events without specifying a prefix. If you really don't want to catch events delete the first 3 lines and use `WScript.CreateObject("Hello.World")` you can then call `Test.Method("Hello World!")`

Comment: No no I want to  catch events without prefix **by modifying the source**. I tried above solution by removing first three lines, but as you said I got nothing echoed, I like very much to know some ways to modify this event in source so I can get this working fine without prefix. I don't need any code, just specify which parts of source to modify to achieve this.

Comment: You cannot catch events without specifying a prefix, what is the problem with doing so?

Comment: No I just like to do this without adding such prefixes, I understood - You say without a prefix, I can't catch events anyway. However, the declaration of this function from another example I found on this site are: `[id(1)] HRESULT Method([in] BSTR sText);` and `STDMETHOD(Method)(BSTR sText) throw()
 {
  ATLTRACE(atlTraceCOM, 4, _T("sText \"%s\"\n"), CString(sText));
  ATLVERIFY(SUCCEEDED(Fire_Event(sText)));
  return S_OK;
 }`. Is there a possibility to return a message like this without those events in COM? I just want to display a message like this from COM dll even without events. :-|

Comment: Make your method return a string?

Comment: Yes yes, I just want to make my method ( like `Test.ShowMessage`) return a string. I will expect to practice with those events about COM later. Like much to replace this event raising function that's in example source with basic string returning function.